# Does wrapping tf.data.Dataset into tf.function improve performance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Given the two examples below, is there a performance improvement when autographing the `tf.data.Dataset`?

Dataset not in tf.function

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.ones([1, 1]) * inputs


model = MyModel()
model2 = MyModel()


@tf.function
def train_step(data):
    output = model(data)
    output = model2(output)
    return output


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.ones([1, 1]))

for data in dataset:
    train_step(data)
```

Dataset in tf.function

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.ones([1, 1]) * inputs


model = MyModel()
model2 = MyModel()


@tf.function
def train():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.ones([1, 1]))
    def train_step(data):
        output = model(data)
        output = model2(output)
        return output
    for data in dataset:
        train_step(data)


train()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `@tf.function` does add significant speedup. Take a look at this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.random.normal((1000, 10, 10, 1))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(data).batch(10)

def iterate_1(dataset):
    for x in dataset:
        x = x

@tf.function
def iterate_2(dataset):
    for x in dataset:
        x = x

%timeit -n 1000 iterate_1(dataset) # 1.46 ms ± 8.2 µs per loop
%timeit -n 1000 iterate_2(dataset) # 239 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop
```

As you can see iterating with `@tf.function` is more than 6 times faster.