# How to combine autograph benefits with a training loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How can I improve the execution speed of the code below using `autograph` "magic"?

Given code from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Especially this part https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan#train_the_model:

```py
def train(dataset, epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    start = time.time()

    for image_batch in dataset:
      train_step(image_batch)

    # Produce images for the GIF as we go
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    generate_and_save_images(generator,
                             epoch + 1,
                             seed)

    # Save the model every 15 epochs
    if (epoch + 1) % 15 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

    print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start))

  # Generate after the final epoch
  display.clear_output(wait=True)
  generate_and_save_images(generator,
                           epochs,
                           seed)
```

And considering the benefits of wrapping a `tf.data.Dataset` into a `@tf.function` call. As demonstrated here: [Does wrapping tf.data.Dataset into tf.function improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038372/does-wrapping-tf-data-dataset-into-tf-function-improve-performance).

**What I have tried:**

Wrapping `train()` into `@tf.function` does not work because of all the other python code within `train`. But: This code is often required for things like logging, checkpointing, etc.

**Question:**

1. How can this code use best of both worlds?
2. Or is it even possible?