# How is tf.data.Dataset use optimised by tf.function in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

The [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2#combine_tfdatadatasets_and_tffunction) of Tensorflow 2.0 advices to use `tf.data.Dataset` along with `tf.function`.

There are two examples of such uses:

- Using a `Dataset` as an argument of a `tf.function`, as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2#combine_tfdatadatasets_and_tffunction):

```py
@tf.function
def train(model, dataset, optimizer):
  for x, y in dataset:
      ....
```

- Creating a local `Dataset` in a `tf.function` body, as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph):

```py
@tf.function
def train(model, optimizer):
  train_ds = mnist_dataset()
  ...
```

Finally, the [autograph doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/tf_function#autograph_and_loops) states that the iterating on a `Dataset` is optimized by `tf.function`.
[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038372/does-wrapping-tf-data-dataset-into-tf-function-improve-performance) shows indeed that using a `Dataset` as a parameter of `tf.function` increases performances.

So, how does `tf.data.Dataset` benefit from `tf.function`, and how can it explain the speedup of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038372/does-wrapping-tf-data-dataset-into-tf-function-improve-performance):

- How is the ["foor loop optimization"](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/tf_function#autograph_and_loops) creating a speedup by itself?
- How is the `Dataset` object treated by the `tf.function` tracer. Like in the parameter or as a local variable examples, how can we use `Dataset` in a `tf.function`, even if the [`tf.function` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/function) suggests that the original function should only accept `Tensor`?
- Is there some kind of communication/sharing between the `Dataset` subgraph (that can then be used in `tf.function` subgraph), or the two are fully separated (meaning that `Dataset` is just used as an black-box iterator from `tf.function`)?